# How do I generate regex for repeating pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Good day! I am working on an interpreter of LOLCODE and I'm having a trouble in this line:

```
SMOOSH "A" AN "B" AN "C" AN "D"
```

I need to get the string literals A,B,C,D but I only got the first and the last two literals.

Here's my code:

```
 r = new Regex(@"(\s+)?(?<smoosh>SMOOSH)\s+(\""(?<yarn1>[^\""]+).*)\s+(\""(?<yarn2>[^\""]+).*)(\s+)?((\s+)(AN)?(\""(?<yarn3>[^\""]+).*))+(\s+)?(?<comment>BTW\s*.*\s*)?$");
```

I need to hold all the string literals so that i could concatenate it later.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: How about `lolcode.Split().Where(token => token.StartsWith("\"") && token.EndsWith("\""))`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"""(.*?)""");
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
      int mIdx=0;
      foreach (Match m in mc)
       {
        for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
          }
        mIdx++;
      }
```

You will get all literals in array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use capturing groups.

```
@"""([^""]*)"""
```

And get the string you want from group index 1.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"""([^""]*)""");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

OR

Use `\G` anchor.`\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. It grabs the values inside double quotes only on the lines which contains the string `SMOOSH`

```
@"(?:(?:\s+)?(?<smoosh>SMOOSH)\s+|(?<!^)\G) *(?:AN)* *""?([^""\n]*)""?"
```

Code:

```
String input = @"SMOOSH ""A"" AN ""B"" AN ""C"" AN ""D""";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:(?:\s+)?(?<smoosh>SMOOSH)\s+|(?<!^)\G) *(?:AN)* *""?([^""\n]*)""?");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rGGWLH)